# SSL for Rest API

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

We are providing Rest API(ASP.NET on IIS7) and one of our customers asked for HTTPS. I do not have any experience with SSL and SSL certificates. Is it enough to buy SSL certificate and install it into IIS7 to get secure HTTPS connection? Do I need to make any modifications in Rest API(ASP.NET) code/config files?

Comment: Please see my article '[WCF: SOAP/REST + SSL + Basic authentification + IIS](http://vgolovchenko.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/wcf-soaprest-ssl-basic-authentification-iis/)'.

Answer (score 1):

please go through below links

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/

Yes, we need first create a Certificate request and then we need to Submit that request to any of the Certificate Authority(CA). This may be your own server with Certificate Server 2.0 installed on it or an online CA such as VeriSign. Contact the certificate provider of your choice and determine the best level of certificate for your needs. After that you will get that certificate from that CA and then we need to install that in IIS.